# Why would this query in Postgres result in a 15-day lock?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Everything in my database was running normally -- reads, writes, lots of activity.

Then I wanted to add a column to the `foos` table. The `foos` table became unavailable. I quit the code executing the query and looked at locks in the system. I found the below query had a lock for 15 days. After that was my table-changing query, and after that were a bunch more queries which involved the `foos` table.

What would cause this query to get stuck for 15 days? This is in 9.1.3

```
select generate_report, b.count from
   (select count(1), date_trunc('hour',f.event_happened_at) from
       foos as f, bars as b
       where age(f.event_happened_at) <= interval '24 hour' and f.id=b.foo_id and b.thing_type='Dog' and b.thing_id=26631
       group by date_trunc('hour',f.event_happened_at)) as e
   right join generate_report(date_trunc('hour',now()) - interval '24 hour',now(),interval '1 hour')
   on generate_report = b.date_trunc
   order by generate_report;
```

**update:** info from `pg_stat_activity`

```
|         backend_start         |          xact_start           |          query_start          | waiting |
-------+---------+----------+------------------+----------------+-----------------+------------------------
| 2012-11-19 18:38:40.029818+00 | 2012-11-19 18:38:40.145172+00 | 2012-11-19 18:38:40.145172+00 | f       |
```

**update:** output of explain:

```
Merge Left Join  (cost=14135.74..14138.08 rows=1000 width=16)
  Merge Cond: (generate_report.generate_report = (date_trunc('hour'::text, f.event_happened_at)))
  ->  Sort  (cost=12.97..13.47 rows=1000 width=8)
        Sort Key: generate_report.generate_report
        ->  Function Scan on generate_report  (cost=0.00..3.00 rows=1000 width=8)
  ->  Sort  (cost=14122.77..14122.81 rows=67 width=16)
        Sort Key: (date_trunc('hour'::text, f.event_happened_at))
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=14121.93..14122.17 rows=67 width=8)
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=3237.14..14121.86 rows=67 width=8)
                    Hash Cond: (b.foo_id = f.id)
                    ->  Index Scan using index_bars_on_thing_type_and_thing_id_and_baz on bars b  (cost=0.00..10859.88 rows=10937 width=4)
                          Index Cond: (((thing_type)::text = 'Dog'::text) AND (thing_id = 26631))
                    ->  Hash  (cost=3131.42..3131.42 rows=30207 width=12)
                          ->  Seq Scan on foos f  (cost=0.00..3131.42 rows=30207 width=12)
                                Filter: (age((('now'::text)::date)::timestamp without time zone, event_happened_at) <= '24:00:00'::interval)
```

Comment: Was the query actually executing? It could just be a problem with lock release.

Comment: @StingyJack presumably not, it certainly didn't need to run for that long. But what state could it be in? What do you mean by a problem with lock release?

Comment: The DBMS will roughly acquire lock, run query, release lock. If the query is still executing, then the problem is not with locking, its that the query is still executing. If the query is not executing, then the problem is with releasing the lock.

Comment: how can i tell if the query is still executing?

Comment: A SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity; would show that info.

Comment: It doesn't look like a lock problem, rather a 'query-runs-forever' problem. You may confirm that by looking a bit at `strace -p pid` (the unix command) where `pid`  is the `procpid` entry for the query in `pg_stat_activity`

Comment: @DanielVérité does "query-runs-forever" mean infinite loop, or waiting for resources, or working on a lot of data... ? (our data is pretty small)

Comment: @John: the strace output should tell what the backend is doing. It may be stuck on any of those things.

Answer (score 1):

Per the info from [pg_stat_activity](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/monitoring-stats.html) you posted, it looks like this query is still executing (waiting = f). This means that the lock just has not been released yet.

You may want to start taking a look at your query to see if there are problems with its structure or the query plan it is generating. 15 days is definitely too long, most long running queries should take no more than 10 minutes before they are considered problems.

For assistance with that, you will need to post your table DDL, some sample data, and some idea of how many rows are in each table. That would probably be best posed as a new question, but you can always edit this one.

Comment: An `EXPLAIN` of the query might help too, especially if it shows a huge estimated cost.

Comment: @John: not much clue from the `explain` output. The estimated cost of 14138 is quite ordinary. It does not predict a long-running query. Also it looks like the generate_report() function is called only once, so even if it's slow it shouldn't affect the query that much. You may try `explain analyze` though it may never finish if it has the same trouble than the initial query.

Comment: k. doesn't that mean 14138 disk accesses?

Comment: The cost is an arbitrary unit that relates to disk and cpu through the configurable [planner cost constants](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-CONSTANTS). For example `seq_page_cost` is the cost of fetching a page in a sequential access. If its value is 1, your query is equivalent for the planner in terms of cost to a sequential fetch of 14k pages (=14k*8k bytes)